# Is it legal to add functionality to a paid aggregator web application through browser extensions?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, terms-of-service, data-ownership

we are stuck with a **Legal** dilemma would appreciate your feedback.

There is a company that aggregates product data from thousands of suppliers and makes it available for a searcher at a subscription fee. Although the details of the products are publicly available, they clearly mention this is **Licensed Data** and **Unauthorized use is strictly prohibited**

The aggregator site is frustrating to use and lacks many features. An important feature that's missing is the ability to review a product and making the review available for other people on the platform.

Our plan was to make an extension that adds the review layer on top of the aggregator website. To do this, we'd need to identify what product the user is currently reviewing and store the unique id (provided by the aggregator) along with the review data (not aggregator's data).

Although we don't plan to scrape/use the data collected by the aggregator, we will need to, at the least store enough information to identify the product.

**ANALOGY**

Consider the following apps:

- A lot of Attorneys use this paid website called [Lexis Nexis](https://www.lexisnexis.com/en-us/home.page).
- [Harvard Business Review](https://w1.buysub.com/pubs/H0/HVR/newbusiness_combo_multistep.jsp?cds_page_id=203760&cds_mag_code=HVR&id=1507321386601&lsid=72791523065025191&vid=1&cds_response_key=I66AHRJD) provides some content exclusively for paid subscribers.

Would it be okay to build an extension that adds publicly visible rating functionality to each of those sites without making their content visible?

**QUESTIONs**

- Is it illegal to add functionality to a paid website? (Please note, we are not making the website data freely.)
- Are we allowed to at least store the unique IDs?
- Can we make changes to the pages (like adding buttons/review sections) to the original page which is behind a paywall?
- Where can I get more information on this?

If you read until here, thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

This would require an attorney to review the specific terms of service and offer legal advice regarding whether your contemplated actions comply with them.

However, it sounds like you're generally describing something that [has been done extensively in the past](https://techcrunch.com/2007/04/10/5-ways-to-mark-up-the-web) and is often called "[web annotation](http://wiki.c2.com/?WebAnnotation)."